# jQuery send ui.value from 2 sliders to a href

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I have one slider and when I drag it, it will send value to specific a href

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider-a').slider({
    value: 50,
    min: 3,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui){
      $('.dl-link').attr('href', '/download/' + ui.value + '/');
    }
  });
});
```

when i drag the slider to 60:

```
<a href="/download/60/">link</a>
```

this works great when i have one slider, but how can i send values of 2 sliders?

second slider:

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider-b').slider({
    value: 80,
    min: 1,
    max: 99,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui){
      $('.dl-link').attr('href', '/download/' + ui.value FROM FIRST SLIDER + '/' + ui.value + '/');
    }
  });
});
```

the final link should look like:

```
<a href="/download/60/55/">link</a>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I simply save the ui.value values then construct the URLs from the saved values.

```
var firstslider = 50;
var secondslider = 80;
$(function() {
  $('.slider-a').slider({
    value: 50,
    min: 3,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui){
      firstslider = ui.value;
      $('.dl-link').attr('href', '/download/' + firstslider + '/' + secondslider + '/');
    }
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('.slider-b').slider({
    value: 80,
    min: 1,
    max: 99,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui){
      secondslider = ui.value;
      $('.dl-link').attr('href', '/download/' + firstslider + '/' + secondslider + '/');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the value of a slider using `$(selector).slider('option', 'value')`.

Therefore your `slide` callback for the second slider could be:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p1dfs6dm/)

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
  var sliderAValue = $('.slider-a').slider('option', 'value');
  $('.dl-link').attr('href', '/download/' + sliderAValue + '/' + ui.value + '/');
}
```

Comment: Was just writing up the same thing, a little differently though -> **http://jsfiddle.net/z97ykcg8/**

Comment: hey @adeneo i like you solution because it's the simplest, but you cannot drag both sliders to min and max values, something's wrong there